# Values do not match data in matlab geographic plot

Tags: matlab, background, colorbar, gis

I am plotting trajectories in Matlab using contourf. I am having an issue with the colors matching the data. I have posted my current image below. All areas that do not have data should be white as they are zero which I specifically specified in the script(they are currently blue-ish which is the the 0.1 to 1 range). In addition, values that are yellow, should be in the blue range(<1). Any suggestions?

Here is the part of my script where I do the plotting:

```
axesm('mercator', 'MapLatLim', latlim, 'MapLonLim', lonlim,...
       'Frame', 'on', 'Grid', 'on', 'MeridianLabel', 'on', 'ParallelLabel', 'on')
setm(gca,'mlabelparallel',-20)
load coastlines
Contours = [0.001 0.01 0.1 1 10 100];
[c,h] = contourfm(latlim, lonlim, u, log(Contours));
colorbar('YTick', log(Contours), 'YTickLabel', Contours);
myColorMap = jet(256).^.3;
myColorMap(1,:) = [1];
colormap(myColorMap)
colorbar
caxis(log([Contours(1) Contours(length(Contours))]));
colorbar('FontSize', 12, 'YTick', log(Contours), 'YTickLabel', Contours);
geoshow(coastlat, coastlon,'Color', 'k')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contour level, `V`, in `contourfm(lat,lon,Z, V)` does not scale your data or colour. It works in a different way than what you thought.

Let's see one example first:

```
u = rand(8)+0.1; u(1:2,:) = 0; u(5:6,:) = 10; u(7:8,:) = 100;
V = [0,1,40,100];
contourfm([0,1], [0,1], u, V);
mycm = jet(256).^.3; mycm(1,:) = 1;
colormap(mycm)
contourcbar('FontSize', 12, 'YTick', V, 'YTickLabel', V);
```

where u is

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.1947  0.6616  0.2413  0.6511  0.4403  0.9112  1.0016  0.5654
0.8422  0.3159  0.5695  0.6478  0.9933  0.1686  0.8387  0.5362
10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

[image: pic1]

As you can see, for `V = [0,1,40,100]` all values from 0 to 1 are white, values from 1 to 40 are cyan and above are red.

Therefore, you must scale your `u` then assign appropriate contour level. Use `contourcbar` instead of `colorbar` to check the colours first.

---

Apart from the problem with contour level, I suspect the `u` parameter contains negative values. The colour at the bottom of the colour bar is always assigned to the minimum z value. You must ensure 0 is the minimum value in `u`, i.e. remove the negative values.

Comment: Though not exactly the issue, your comment helped my to realize what the problem was. I was just doing math wrong and found that if I wanted the final value to be zero then I had to take the log of 1 and go from there. In addition,the function log was not what I needed but actually log10. Thank you so much!